# Which twitter API supports favoriting a tweet? How do favor a tweet in Android app?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I think that one needs to be logged into twitter to favor a tweet.  Currently I am using Twitter  API ME but I am no sure it supports favoriting a tweet?  I am already using Twitter API ME for logging in, can I keep this API or do I need to move on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) on android it also has the API to [favorite an Tweet](http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/api/FavoriteMethods.html)..